# Syntax error on token "||", invalid OnlySynchronized

Tags: java, operators

I'm getting an error on this line and I'm not sure why. I believe it may have to do with my OR operator - but I'm really not sure.

```
if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains("//USR;1")) || 
         (extras.getString(Constants.PREFS_KEY_CALL_MADE).contains("TRUE")) {
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parenthesis are not balanced, you have an extra `)`, try this:

```
                                                        One `)` was removed 
                                                                ٧٧٧
if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains("//USR;1") || 
   (extras.getString(Constants.PREFS_KEY_CALL_MADE).contains("TRUE")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (
    (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains("//USR;1")) 
    ||
    (extras.getString(Constants.PREFS_KEY_CALL_MADE).contains("TRUE"))
) {
```

One bracket was missing.